# BillingClient and PurchasesUpdateListener classes not available

Tags: android, dependencies, in-app-billing, gradle-dependencies

I'm trying to add in-app billing as described here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate
and think I have set up dependencies as instructed, but still, both the BillingClient and PurchasesUpdateListener classes as in the code example on the page are not available.

My project's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {   
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.1'
}
```

My top-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: where are your classes? IS android studio showing error on them? If so clean and rebuild after invalidating cache and restarting the studio

Comment: in Android Studio, when I write "import com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener;" , "billingclient" is marked red. Regardless if I 'clean project' or restart Android Studio before… strange.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my global build.gradle as follows helped me to resolve the missing dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    maven { url "https://maven.springframework.org/release" }
    maven { url "https://maven.restlet.com" }
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the global build.gradle is using the latest versions.
Then resyncing will resolve all the issues.